# Unique pointer with incomplete type - c++2b?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, c++23

It boils down to:

```
#include <memory>
class dummy;

std::unique_ptr<dummy> test;

class dummy {

};
```

When compiled with clang++-14 with c++2b:

It gives briefly:

```
clang++ ../bugl.cpp -I /usr/lib/llvm-14/include  -std=c++2b
In file included from ../bugl.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/memory:76:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/bits/unique_ptr.h:93:16: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'dummy'
        static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/bits/unique_ptr.h:396:4: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::default_delete<dummy>::operator()' requested here
          get_deleter()(std::move(__ptr));
          ^
../bugl.cpp:4:24: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::unique_ptr<dummy>::~unique_ptr' requested here
std::unique_ptr<dummy> test;
                       ^
../bugl.cpp:2:7: note: forward declaration of 'dummy'
class dummy;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

But it becomes interesting once we remove the definition of `dummy` - then it fails equally everywhere.

Originally I found it from the llvm-14 headers:

```
#include <memory>
#include <llvm/ADT/APFloat.h>
```

Using llvm-14 and libstdc++-12-dev with clang++-14 from Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Compiling with:

```
clang++ -std=c++2b bugllvm.cpp
```

With `-std=c++20` it compiles fine (as well as 20 and 2b with g++).

Basically the offending line is this one:

```
class DoubleAPFloat final : public APFloatBase {
  // Note: this must be the first data member.
  const fltSemantics *Semantics;
  std::unique_ptr<APFloat[]> Floats;
```

Where `APFloat` is declared but not defined at this point:

```
class APFloat;
```

My question is where is the bug lays - in the compiler, the standard library, the standard itself?

Maybe it's something else.

Comment: I would present the last snippet at the beginning of the question, then the command and the error, and then everything else.

Comment: This looks like this LLVM bug: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/59784

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not using `std::unique_ptr` as a member as such. The actual problem is further down in the class definition in the implementation of `operator=` in line 625:

```
DoubleAPFloat &operator=(DoubleAPFloat &&RHS) {
    if (this != &RHS) {
      this->~DoubleAPFloat();
      new (this) DoubleAPFloat(std::move(RHS));
    }
    return *this;
  }
```

The destructor call causes the destructor of `DoubleAPFloat` to be defined. This requires the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<APFloat[]>` to be instantiated. The instantiation of that destructor requires instantiation of `std::default_delete<APFloat[]>`'s `operator()` which in turn requires `APFloat` to be complete.

The instantiation of a function template specialization has two points of instantiation. One immediately following the namespace scope declaration requiring it (or at the point of the template instantiation from which it is required) and the second at the end of the translation unit. If choosing one of them over the other would give the program a different meaning, then the program is *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*.

`APFloat` is defined later in the header file, so this applies here. The instantiation of `std::default_delete<APFloat[]>::operator()` would be ill-formed immediately after the definition of `DoubleAPFloat` (where the instantiation of `std::unique_ptr`'s destructor has one point of instantiation), but it would be well-formed at the end of the translation unit.

So this is a bug in `<llvm/ADT/APFloat.h>` which a compiler doesn't have to diagnose.

---

The same applies to your reduced test case. The definition of `test` requires the destructor to be defined since it is needed to destruct the variable. Again the implicit instantiation may be placed immediately after the variable definition or at the end of the translation unit. Without the definition of `dummy` at the end, both points of instantiation are ill-formed, so that now the compiler is required to diagnose it.

Comment: But have you checked my example - it turns out it exhibits the same behavior. At least on my side,

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions For the same reason. The variable definition also requires the destructor. But a member declaration itself doesn't since it doesn't cause any object to be created until an object of the enclosing class is actually created.

Comment: So clang++ with c++2b mode just has additional diagnostics in place then?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions I don't know what that changes internally. It might be affecting the instantiation strategy due to some changes in the core language between the two versions. But I can only speculate on that.

Comment: So a solution would be to move the definition of this operator out of line then (for the broken header)? I'm going to try this anyway.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions Yes, it should be implemented after the definition of `APFloat`.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions Actually it might be caused by `std::unique_ptr` becoming `constexpr`-friendly in C++23. Clang might be making the instantiation decision differently because the relevant functions are marked `constexpr` (only) with `-std=c++2b`.